# curl with variable in url using javascript gets me error

Tags: javascript, curl, synology

```
var Cname = "test";
var Cphone = "01022223333";
var getSynoLink = "curl --location --request GET";
getSynoLink += " 'https://test.synology.me:9005/webapi/entry.cgi?api=SYNO.FileStation.Sharing&version=3&";
getSynoLink += "method=create&";
getSynoLink += "password=" + Cphone + "&";
getSynoLink += "path=/E-MAIL/"+ Cname + "_" + Cphone +"'";
getSynoLink += " -H 'Cookie: id=1233456454121'";
```

I am trying to create sharing link on synology nas using synology api.
Everything works great except the password part.
I am setting password from Cphone(customer's phone number).

So far it creates link but if I put password, says incorrect.

I've tried,

```
 getSynoLink += "password=01022223333&";
```

But it comes with incorrect password.

```
getSynoLink += "password=world&";
```

If i put string like "world" it works.

As of synology api document,

> Optional The password for the sharing link
> password when accessing it. The max password length are 16 characters. String

I guess it is problem of numbers and string.

But its doable on GUI interface.

I've tried

```
var Cphone = "01022223333";
var Pass2 = Cphone.toString();
var Pass1 = Cphone + "";
var Pass = String(Cphone);
```

ended up with no luck.

please help me...

Answer (score 0):

`01022223333` must be quoted, otherwise it is treated as the numeric value `1022223333` or even the octal representation of the decimal value `139011803`.

```
getSynoLink += "password=%22" + Cphone + "%22&";
```

Comment: wow.. you are such a hero. Thanks